# Multiple Redis transactions (multi/exec) in single pipeline using Jedis

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I'm using [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) and I'd like to create a single Pipeline which contains multiple independent transactions (multi/exec blocks).

From what I've seen so far, it seems that is only possible to toggle a whole Pipeline into an atomic Transaction.

```
Pipeline pipeline = jedis.pipelined();
pipeline.multi(); // Does not return a Jedis Transaction
// From there, everything done on Pipeline is in a single transaction.
```

I would have expected `pipeline.multi()` to return a `Transaction`.

I suspect that having the whole pipeline in a single transaction is going to cost more than having multiple smaller transaction blocks in a single pipeline.

Is this something that is supported by Redis?
If yes, is this something that can be done using Jedis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more tests and digging, it appears that I can call `pipeline.multi()` and `pipeline.exec()` more than once and thus create multiple transactional blocks.

Comment: can you share the link where you have found this.

Comment: when you say you can call multi and exec pairs more than once, doesn't that mean the commands passed before each exec would be executed. this beats the purpose of a pipeline if there are round trips to redis server.

Comment: This was nearly 3 years ago.. I don't remember the link, sorry @Abhishek

I'm unsure if mulitple `pipeline.exec()` results in multiple round trips. I vaguely remembers that this is the technique that I ended up using and that it indeed solved my issue. Sorry I can't be more helpful!